# Spamassasin user - disable shell

Tags: security, permissions, spamassassin, passwd

I recently discovered that spamassasin added the following line to my passwd file:
`debian-spamd:x:115:122::/var/lib/spamassassin:/bin/sh`. Why does spamassasin need shell access? Is it safe to disable shell access (f.e. set shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`).

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Debian bug #918506](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918506), the package’s post-install script uses `su` to execute a command under the debian-spam user. This is impossible if the user doesn’t have a valid shell, so changing the shell to nologin will cause re-configurations and upgrades of the spamassassin package to fail whenever gnupg is also installed (since gnupg must be installed for the affected command to execute).